# Python multiprocessing, parsing one item of a list and a full list as arguments into process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to compare the coordinate data points in two lists by calculating the distance between each combination of points. I want to run a process in parallel that will send one data point and a set of datapoints to a function.

```
def main(data1,data2):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.submit(segmentData,dataPoint,dataList)
        for result in results:
            if result != None:
                newData2.append(result)
```

At the moment if I give a list as the argument it iterates through every point in the list, how do I make the second argument the full list of points?

Comment: Instead do matrix multiplication.

Comment: Fix your code fragment to clarify where do `segmentData,dataPoint,dataList` come from

Comment: ***"make the second argument the full list"***: Change to `..., (dataPoint,), ...`